# Unwanted shutdown of Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: shutdown

Since 4 days I have a problem of unwanted shutdown. I'm using my Ubuntu 22.04 normally as always (even if it's just moving files), then the apps close suddenly and I have to press "power" again.

I checked `/var/log/syslog` and all I have is this:

```
Jan 20 10:28:15 cesar-linux2 systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
Jan 20 10:28:16 cesar-linux2 systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 20 10:28:16 cesar-linux2 systemd[1]: Finished Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Jan 20 10:28:48 cesar-linux2 kernel: [  935.210499] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: reached 10 old SN frames from cc:2d:1b:33:4a:85 on queue 2, stopping BA session on TID 4
Jan 20 10:30:01 cesar-linux2 CRON[4309]: (root) CMD ([ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start >/dev/null; fi)
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@Jan 20 10:36:30 cesar-linux2 kernel: [    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x3c, date = 2022-03-23
```

What could be the cause of this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe there is a hardware problem? Try a memory check first.

Comment: I know some basic commands (https://phoenixnap.com/kb/linux-commands-check-memory-usage) but I don't know what to do after that. How can I detect if something is wrong?

Comment: Because the health of your system is likely compromised, the common way is to boot from an external device and run a memory test. https://www.system-rescue.org/.